# Pass dynamic values to ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

When I do this, site works in the tag, but it throws an error for the function args. When I only use one set of braces, nothing shows there. What is the proper way to set these dynamic function args in a view?

```
<a ng-click="viewThisGraph({{site}}, {{cur_action}})" href="#">{{site}}</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be pass variable without `{{}}`(interpolation)

```
ng-click="viewThisGraph(site, cur_action)"
```

Also remove `href="#"` from the anchor, which will prevent unnecessary route navigation to default state.

Comment: I think href should be there or else it would not look like a hyperlink, it should be just `href` instead of `href="#"`, just a suggestion :)

Comment: @NarenMurali thanks for heads up. I meant to say, remove `#` which would be problematic. And about styling it depends on how you applied CSS rules.

Answer (score 1):

You may try for this:

```
<a ng-click="viewThisGraph(site,cur_action)">{{site}}</a>
```

whenever you are trying to send some variables and object and some constant values to ng-click function event, then dont need to use **{{}}**,

**because it has already attached with event binding,**